# ASP.net part of layout and javascript not running after publication to server

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, fullcalendar

I've got a finished ASP.NET MVC project. It runs perfectly on computers with visual studio and IIS express. No errors and the functionality works fine. But it does not load a part of the css and Jquery/javascript(fullcalendar) if i publish and run it on the server. Also, the published project does not load on some computers at all.

I found the following error in the browser console:

```
TypeError: $(...).fullCalendar is not a function
```

and

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).fullCalendar is not a function
undefined
jquery.min.js:2:30920
```

Server is running IIS and .NET Core 2.0.

What did i do wrong?

Comment: Do you have any  <environment Names="Production"> that wraps the JS files?

Comment: this simply indicates that the JS file was not loaded correctly into the page, or at least did not load until after code which relies on it was executed. Since you claim it works in some environments, it's most likely a deployment issue. Check it got published to the server correctly in the right location and that the webserver has permission to access it. If you look in your browser's network tab as the page is loaded you might see that the fullcalendar file has an error status next to it e.g. 404 or 403 indicating that the file didn't load properly

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you are using the correct Jquery versions.
2. Call your jquery file/CDN before the other javascript using jquery.